# How to load random div tags when page loads

Tags: javascript

whenever I load or refresh the homepages, then images and content changes, how to do this?

Is there any Javascript code to do this?

Kindly share

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a tour of the help center to see what types of question to ask here.  This question is off topic for the site

Answer (score 0):

It's not easy, but you can save content (text, images src, etc) into array, then put that array into another array. 
Then, simply generate random number (within the range ArrayOfContents.length) and then load stuff from that array into page.

Comment: can you send me a demo link